# Objective-C: Unknown Type Name Error

Tags: objective-c, types, nsmutabledictionary

I have my main class and a SiteValue class. The error "Unknown type name" is appearing in my main class. I am trying to create a mutable dictionary of SiteValue objects.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = nil;

 //The line below shows the error
    SiteValue* person1 = [SiteValue siteValueWithUsername: @"person1"     andPassword: @"123" andCount: 0];

}
return 0;

}
```

SiteValue.h file:

```
@interface SiteValue : NSObject

+(SiteValue*) siteValueWithUsername: (NSString *)username andPassword: (NSString *)password andCount: (int) count;

@end
```

Comment: Did you import `SiteValue.h` into your main.m file?

Comment: Oh right, I forgot that, thank you!